# jqgrid column chooser hide on first load

Tags: jqgrid

I replicated from the [samples](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser5.htm) and working fine, I want to know if it's possible to hide several column on 1st load, so by default only some column shown on grid.

Comment: Do you just need to hide some columns on 1st time load?

Comment: yes, the hidden column should be available on left pane column chooser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the column on first load, you can set the `hidden` option in `colModel` to true. For example if you would like to initialy hide the *note* column of the sample you have mentioned, you would change the `colModel` like this:

```
$grid.jqGrid({
    ...
    colModel: [
        ...
        { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 60, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea', hidden: true }
    ],
    ...
});
```

The `columnChooser` will properly pick up this column and place it in *"make visible"* pane, so user can show it.